# AJAX, PHP, MYSQL - innerHTML not working & Neither any Alternatives

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, dom, innerhtml

I am a noob and i am trying to get this script working. It works perfectly in all browsers except IE. I have tried most of the solutions here on stackoverflow but none of them works for me. I am doing some kiddish mistake somewhere which I am unable to spot. Would request your help.

Also just to let you know the DOM Objects format of using appendchild might not work 100% correctly for me since this script basically passes values from a drop down which shows say numbers from 1 to 10 and based on those numbers it pulls up corresponding charts. So if I am viewing chart 1 then i can go ahead and select the drop down to view chart 3 as well. But if we use the appendchild property, it only allows me to see one of the charts by selecting 1 to 10 and it doesn't work unless I refresh the page. So unless deletechild is used I think it would not work, just my guess. Hence, I have commented that section out and I am using the good old method of innerhtml.

This is my JS function.

```
function showUser(str) {

debugger;

var xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject("Browser does not support HTTP Request");

if (str=="") {
  document.getElementById("pairname").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 

  /* <-- I HAVE ALREADY COMMENTED THIS OUT & am using a more robust function for this.
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  */

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("pairname").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    //AS YOU CAN SEE THE ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION OF USING DOM OBJECTS HAS BEEN COMMENTED OUT.. SINCE THIS IS ALSO NOT WORKING IN IE FOR ME.
    //var wrappingElement = document.createElement("div");
    //wrappingElement.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    //document.getElementById('pairname').appendChild(wrappingElement);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getimgdetails.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

function GetXmlHttpObject(errorMessage) {
    var r = false;
    try { r = new XMLHttpRequest(); }// Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    catch(e) {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try { r = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }// older IE
        catch(e) {
            try { r = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }// IE 5+
            catch(e) {// AJAX not possible
                if(errorMessage) { alert(errorMessage); }
            }
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

AND THIS IS WHERE I AM SHOWING IT

```
<div id="pairname"><b>Charts will  be shown here.</b></div>*
```

AND this is the Script which receives and sends back the info. SO basically it shows 5 charts for each number 1 to 10.

```
$q=$_GET["q"];

 Echo "<img src=mqluploads/".$q."15.gif?".time()."></img>";
 Echo "<br>";
 Echo "---------------------------------------------------------";
 Echo "<br>";   

 Echo "<img src=mqluploads/".$q."60.gif?".time()."></img>";
 Echo "<br>";
 Echo "---------------------------------------------------------";
 Echo "<br>";

 Echo "<img src=mqluploads/".$q."240.gif?".time()."></img>";
 Echo "<br>";
 Echo "---------------------------------------------------------";
 Echo "<br>";

 Echo "<img src=mqluploads/".$q."1440.gif?".time()."></img>";
 Echo "<br>";
 Echo "---------------------------------------------------------";
 Echo "<br>";

 Echo "<img src=mqluploads/".$q."10080.gif?".time()."></img>";
 Echo "<br>";
 Echo "---------------------------------------------------------";
 Echo "<br>";

 Echo "<img src=mqluploads/".$q."43200.gif?".time()."></img>";
 Echo "<br>";
 Echo "---------------------------------------------------------";
 Echo "<br>";
?>
```

Many many thanks in advance for your help and for reading this far. I have been struggling with this for the past one week and now finally decided to seek some help. Looking forward to your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that your php script is returning some data. Try to access getimgdetails.php?q=str (replace str with correct paremeter) directly in browser.

Also place an alert(xmlhttp.responseText) before this line:

document.getElementById("pairname").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

This will help you to debug.

Comment: It is working in firefox, chrome but IE is the problem. It doesn't work in IE. Even if I replace the statements **"document.getElementById("pairname").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;"** with DOM statements which I have commented in the script above...It still doesn't work in IE.